# Releasing app for internal testing on Google Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, expo

This is first time me releasing app so I'm facing this issue

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key.

This app was already released for internal testing for old version by some other developer.
He didn't wrote **keystore password** and **keyStore** alias in **gradle.properties** file. I don't know how he did it but I don't have any access to it. Is there any way I could create new keystore and upload it? There is a **debug.keystore** file availble in android/app folder.

Comment: You can mail google for the replacement of keystore.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a new version you must need that keystore file to know that this is the updated version otherwise it will not consider it, you have to create a new app on google console

Comment: can i delete all older published version on play console and upload new one? There is a file named "debug.keystore" in repo but keystore variables are not set in grage.properties file. Is there way to bypass or extract keystore variables? and please also tell me if debug.keystore is the correct file?

Comment: no its not debug.keystore its a default file
The name of keystore depnds on developer some developer remain it to my-key-store.keystore and some chnaged it to other name

Comment: You cannot create a new app with the same name so there is not any need to delete the pervious app... just create a new app and upload it and save your new generated keystore in a safe place... and by default its not uploaded on github because git by default add this keystore in its .gitignore file